# Zillow API mortgage calculator broken?

Tags: javascript, api, zillow

I've been working with Zillow's Mortgage API - specifically GetMonthlyPayments, and it appears to have just gone down, along with all associated documentation and URLs (http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetMonthlyPayments.htm). Anyone have any insight into what's happened or why? No response from Zillow customer support.

Comment: Follow up question here - does anyone know of a comparable open API for mortgage calculations (e.g. monthly payments, taxes, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a contact at Zillow and asked them what happened to their mortgage calculator.

Response: "They killed it. I don't know why."  And an apology about there being no communications around this.